# Scala weird map function behaviour

Tags: scala

Why does the following code work?

```
scala> List(1,2,3) map "somestring"
res0: List[Char] = List(o, m, e)
```

It works in both 2.9 and 2.10.
Looking into the typer:

```
[master●●] % scala -Xprint:typer -e 'List(1,2,3) map "somestring"'                                                                                ~/home/folone/backend
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd2632231162205778968.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val args: Array[String] = argv;
      {
        final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
          def <init>(): anonymous class $anon = {
            $anon.super.<init>();
            ()
          };
          immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3).map[Char, List[Char]](scala.this.Predef.wrapString("somestring"))(immutable.this.List.canBuildFrom[Char])
        };
        {
          new $anon();
          ()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like it gets converted to the [`WrappedString`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString), which has an apply method. This explains, how it works, but does not explain, how a `WrappedString` got accepted into a parameter of type `A => B` (as specified in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)). Can someone explain, how this happens, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By way of `collection.Seq[Char]`, which is a subtype of `PartialFunction[Int, Char]`, which is a subtype of `Int => Char`:

```
scala> implicitly[collection.immutable.WrappedString <:< (Int => Char)]
res0: <:<[scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString,Int => Char] = <function1>
```

So there's only one implicit conversion happening—the original `String => WrappedString`, which kicks in because we're treating a string like a function.

Answer (score 4):

Because `WrappedString` has as a supertype `(Int) => Char`:

[Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) and expand the 'linear supertypes' section.

Comment: I did not notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Others have made it clear that your String implements a function that takes an Int and returns a char (that's the Int=>Char notation). This allows code like this:

```
scala> "Word".apply(3)
res3: Char = d
```

Expanding your example will make it more clear, maybe:

```
List(1,2,3).map(index => "somestring".apply(index))
List(1,2,3).map(index => "somestring"(index)) //(shorter, Scala doesn't require the apply)
List(1,2,3).map("somestring"(_)) //(shorter, Scala doesn't require you to name the value passed in to map) 
List(1,2,3).map("somestring") //(shorter, Scala doesn't require you to explicitly pass the argmument if you give it a single-arg function)
```

Comment: `List(1,2,3) map "somestring"` shorter: sometimes Scala doesn't require you to put dot for method call and wrapping argument in braces :-)